# How to select the id of the drop down menu from the Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in the database with the name: gstn_document_type_master.

I am using the following code to print the options in a drop down from a column "DOC_DESC" from the table (it is working fine).

```
<?php 
    echo $form->dropdownlist(
            $model, 'dn_id', 
            CHtml::listData(GstndocumenttypemasterForm::model()->findAll(
                    array("order" => "DOC_TYPE_CODE asc")), 
                    'ID', 'DOC_DESC'), 
            array('empty' => 'Select','class' => 'textInput')
        );
?>
```

When the user selects a particular option and submits it, the particular "DOC_TYPE_CODE" should be printed.

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
   // DOC_TYPE_CODE should be printed here
}
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump( $_POST );` and see if it contains anything.  I do not know which framework you are using so don't know if it is constructing the form with names but the select within the form will require a name to be submitted.